# Module name collision with built-in types

Tags: typescript

I have the following situation:

```
module Foo.Audio {
    export class Bar {
        constructor() {
            var a = new Audio();  // Error because we're in Foo.Audio module
        }
    }
}
```

I can of course use casting but that seems like a silly alternative.  Is there any way (besides changing my module name or casting) to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope. No way other than casting. You can open a bug at : http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic and put a link here. I would vote for it.